# multi-thread saftey for read threads while other thread is writing for the shared data using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr

```cpp
class Buffer{
public:
    Buffer()=default;

    void write(int id) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        // update data
        if (database.find(id) != database.end()) {
            std::shared_ptr<Data> data = database.at(id);

            data->update(/* something*/);
        }
        // create new data
        else {
            std::shared_ptr<Data> new_data = std::make_shared<Data>();
            new_data->update(/* something */)

            database[id] = new_data;               
        }
    }

    shared_ptr<Data> read(int id) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::shared_ptr<Data> data; 

        // get data if exists
        if (database.find(id) != database.end()) {
            data = database[id];
        }

        return data;
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx;

    std::map<int, shared_ptr<Data>> database;

};
```

I have a class Buffer, the pseudocode is above. In my code, I have one thread to keep writing the buffer by `write()`, and other threads to read the buffer by `auto data = buffer.read()`.

**So My question** is: the `data` will have corrupted performance since the `data` may be written in another thread?

Comment: You will need a [shared_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) (reader/writer lock) for that. Article [Reader-Writer Locks (modernes C++)](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/reader-writer-locks). I am not sure you even need sharer_ptr's in this case (a reference to the data would do as long as the database outlives the threads)

Comment: The code you've shown is OK. However, there's a good change that the code you haven't shown - the code calling `read` and then doing something with the returned `Data` - will trigger a data race. Unless something else, also not shown, ensures that `Data::update` is OK to run concurrently with other uses of this `Data` object.

Comment: You could probably do better than doing 2 lookups, e.g.: `if (auto pos = database.find(id); pos != database.end()) { data = *pos; }`

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided why do you block the read operation to only one thread, read can be done concurrently. Code below may improve read operation.

```
class Buffer{
public:
    Buffer()=default;

    void write(int id) {
        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lck(mtx);

        // update data
        if (database.find(id) != database.end()) {
            std::shared_ptr<Data> data = database.at(id);

            data->update(/* something*/);
        }
        // create new data
        else {
            std::shared_ptr<Data> new_data = std::make_shared<Data>();
            new_data->update(/* something */)

            database[id] = new_data;               
        }
    }

    shared_ptr<Data> read(int id) {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::shared_ptr<Data> data; 

        // get data if exists
        if (database.find(id) != database.end()) {
            data = database[id];
        }

        return data;
    }

private:
    std::shared_mutex mtx;

    std::map<int, shared_ptr<Data>> database;

};
```

so `write()` function, still can acquire exclusive lock with `std::unique_lock` to ensure only one thread can write at a time.

But `read()` function acquires a shared lock using `std::shared_lock`, allowing multiple threads to read concurrently.

By using `std::shared_mutex`, multiple threads can safely read at the same time from shared resources but write will require exclusive access.

Though to answer your question even your current code should not have data corruption, as shared data in both `read` and `write` are unique locked.